# How to get images using Gravatar image requests

Tags: gravatar

I am trying to build a plugin for Joomla which would access information from a Gravatar account and would display the information. Gravatar documentation has the source code and the information to display the avatar as a url. Is there anyway which i could retrieve the image direct?!

Thank you.

Comment: If you know how to construct the url to the avatar you can download it too.

Comment: Thank you i will let you know soon after implementing this.